# How to get last value from firebase database to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm sending to firebase database information about humidity (value and time, showed in the link below and I have a question how can I get information about last measurement (value and time) in javascript because I want to show on the website information only about last measurement

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do this is by attaching a timestamp to all of your documents ([`new Date().toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) in javascript) and then checking to find the most recent one using firebase `.where()` function in firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries.

This is assuming you're using firebase firestore. If you're using firebase realtime DB there should be a way to apply this concept of checking the most recent timestamps, just with different code.

Comment: I just saw your image and realized you're using realtime DB. In the future please make that clear in your question.

Comment: Also instead of using .where() refer to the documentation for realtime DB: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

That'd be:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref("Humidity");
const query = ref.orderByChild("time").limitToLast(1);
query.once("child_added").then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val().value);
});
```

I recommend reading:

- the documentation on [reading from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)
- the documentation on [ordering/filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).